# The meaning of the phrase 'send over to someone'

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

I got an example:

> A nice chap has asked me to send over to you a fee proposal for...

The dictionaries 'Longman Phrasal Verbs' (App for iPhone), 'Macmillan Phrasal Verbs Plus' (2008) and 'Oxford Dictionary of English' (App for iPhone) do not provide the meaning of this phrase.

Because of 'over', the phrase gives me a feeling that the proposal will be given directly to me without any intermediary (or some sort of internal approval) in between.  But, of course, and as usual, I may be wrong.

I am anxious for any explanation you may give.

Answer (score 1):

["**To send something over to someone**"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/send%20over) means

> to dispatch across the sea, through the air, or from one place to another

Here's another definition from [the Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/send+over)

> to cause something to be taken to some place.
>
> *I sent the package over to your home. Please send over the rest of the mail.*

The particle "over" implies a movement of the object from one place to another. And the preposition "to" marks the indirect object, "you" in your case.